# "DenseToSparseBatchDataset" device_type: "CPU" for unknown op: DenseToSparseBatchDataset

Tags: python, linux, keras, tensorflow

After a lot of fiddling, tensorflow built from sources and installed into Python 3.5 (it didn't seem to like 3.6) and now a Keras program runs in the notebook without any complaining from tensorflow as before, something was not installed to standards. But, it does seem to use the CPU heavily:

[image: CPU monitor]

and the GPU lightly:

```
$ nvidia-smi
Fri Nov 10 18:13:11 2017       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 375.26                 Driver Version: 375.26                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 105...  Off  | 0000:01:00.0      On |                  N/A |
|  0%   49C    P0    36W /  72W |   3740MiB /  4030MiB |     28%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      2283    G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                             273MiB |
|    0      3411    G   cinnamon                                       155MiB |
|    0     14388    C   /storageHDD/tensorflow/bin/python3            3307MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

From the messages in the output of the jupyter kernel it looks like it has made a conscious decision to use the CPU rather than the GPU:

```
[I 17:20:45.588 NotebookApp] Adapting to protocol v5.1 for kernel a3c0afcc-e525-48e5-8f54-75a349214f96
2017-11-10 17:20:50.857309: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:900] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2017-11-10 17:20:50.857625: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1061] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 1050 Ti major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.43
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
totalMemory: 3.94GiB freeMemory: 3.45GiB
2017-11-10 17:20:50.857643: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1151] Creating TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1050 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2017-11-10 17:21:43.862726: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1142] OpKernel ('op: "DenseToSparseBatchDataset" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: DenseToSparseBatchDataset
2017-11-10 17:21:43.862770: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1142] OpKernel ('op: "GroupByWindowDataset" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: GroupByWindowDataset
2017-11-10 17:21:43.862783: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1142] OpKernel ('op: "IgnoreErrorsDataset" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: IgnoreErrorsDataset
2017-11-10 17:21:43.862803: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1142] OpKernel ('op: "DatasetToSingleElement" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: DatasetToSingleElement
2017-11-10 17:21:43.862817: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1142] OpKernel ('op: "SerializeIterator" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: SerializeIterator
2017-11-10 17:21:43.862836: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1142] OpKernel ('op: "DeserializeIterator" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: DeserializeIterator
2017-11-10 17:21:43.862845: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1142] OpKernel ('op: "MapAndBatchDataset" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: MapAndBatchDataset
2017-11-10 17:21:43.862867: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1142] OpKernel ('op: "ParallelInterleaveDataset" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: ParallelInterleaveDataset
2017-11-10 17:21:43.862891: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1142] OpKernel ('op: "ScanDataset" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: ScanDataset
2017-11-10 17:21:43.862910: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1142] OpKernel ('op: "SqlDataset" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: SqlDataset
2017-11-10 17:21:45.342326: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1151] Creating TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1050 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2017-11-10 17:21:45.621793: W tensorflow/core/grappler/utils.cc:48] Node ConstantFolding/training/Adam/gradients/batch_normalization_1/batchnorm/add_grad/BroadcastGradientArgs-0 is not in the graph.
2017-11-10 17:21:45.621852: W tensorflow/core/grappler/utils.cc:48] Node ConstantFolding/training/Adam/gradients/batch_normalization_1/batchnorm/add_grad/BroadcastGradientArgs-1 is not in the graph.
2017-11-10 17:21:45.622311: W tensorflow/core/grappler/utils.cc:48] Node ConstantFolding/training/Adam/gradients/batch_normalization_1/cond/batchnorm/sub_grad/BroadcastGradientArgs-0 is not in the graph.
2017-11-10 17:21:45.622332: W tensorflow/core/grappler/utils.cc:48] Node ConstantFolding/training/Adam/gradients/batch_normalization_1/cond/batchnorm/sub_grad/BroadcastGradientArgs-1 is not in the graph.
2017-11-10 17:21:45.622394: W tensorflow/core/grappler/utils.cc:48] Node ConstantFolding/training/Adam/gradients/batch_normalization_1/batchnorm/sub_grad/BroadcastGradientArgs-0 is not in the graph.
2017-11-10 17:21:45.622411: W tensorflow/core/grappler/utils.cc:48] Node ConstantFolding/training/Adam/gradients/batch_normalization_1/batchnorm/sub_grad/BroadcastGradientArgs-1 is not in the graph.
2017-11-10 17:21:45.622470: W tensorflow/core/grappler/utils.cc:48] Node ConstantFolding/training/Adam/gradients/batch_normalization_2/batchnorm/add_grad/BroadcastGradientArgs-0 is not in the graph.
```

What is the meaning of all those lines containing `device_type: "CPU"` ?

Does anyone know if that is normal or if it is perhaps a sign that a dependency is missing somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following lines containing warning messages were accidentally added by a [recent change](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/dacce477d4831540dda1e68d6d0f8f017aab0020#diff-715be560c901ec7399775da6b2f10d3a):

```
2017-11-10 17:21:43.862726: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1142] OpKernel ('op: "DenseToSparseBatchDataset" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: DenseToSparseBatchDataset
2017-11-10 17:21:43.862770: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1142] OpKernel ('op: "GroupByWindowDataset" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: GroupByWindowDataset
2017-11-10 17:21:43.862783: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1142] OpKernel ('op: "IgnoreErrorsDataset" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: IgnoreErrorsDataset
2017-11-10 17:21:43.862803: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1142] OpKernel ('op: "DatasetToSingleElement" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: DatasetToSingleElement
2017-11-10 17:21:43.862817: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1142] OpKernel ('op: "SerializeIterator" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: SerializeIterator
2017-11-10 17:21:43.862836: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1142] OpKernel ('op: "DeserializeIterator" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: DeserializeIterator
2017-11-10 17:21:43.862845: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1142] OpKernel ('op: "MapAndBatchDataset" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: MapAndBatchDataset
2017-11-10 17:21:43.862867: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1142] OpKernel ('op: "ParallelInterleaveDataset" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: ParallelInterleaveDataset
2017-11-10 17:21:43.862891: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1142] OpKernel ('op: "ScanDataset" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: ScanDataset
2017-11-10 17:21:43.862910: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1142] OpKernel ('op: "SqlDataset" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: SqlDataset
```

That change has since been [reverted](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/f0b1e65b0ac9e587c117485a96a0eaf40675c518#diff-715be560c901ec7399775da6b2f10d3a), and the warning messages should no longer be printed.

Comment: Thanks @mrry I had a look through that _"This change moves the contrib-level Dataset ops out of the core op libraries..."_ I only reinstalled Tensorflow a few days ago, are you saying that the _"unknow op"_ is now known and might happen on the GPU or it is still unknown, but just the messages will go away?  If it is the former maybe should go through the whole install from sources again to benefit from this change, although it did take like more than half an hour to build that wheel file..